# Assign Image To ZKTeco Device

Tags: c#, sdk, zkteco

I am trying to assign image to **ZKTeco** device with the model SFace900. Purpose is to recognize user on face detection. I've a SDK that works fine to download attendance from device using a `C#` app, in the same time I can see two default methods is given to assign image or user face as follows:

```
axCZKEM1.SetUserFace()
axCZKEM1.SetUserFaceStr()
```

I am not sure but I think it requires **base64** string to transfer image to the device. So I tried something like this:

```
private void SetUserFaceStr(string val)
{
   zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
   axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IP, Port);
   
   int idwErrorCode = 0;
   var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val);

       
   if (axCZKEM1.SetUserFaceStr(axCZKEM1.MachineNumber, userId, 50, val, byteString.Length))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("SetUserFaceStr!", "Success");
   }
   else
   {
      axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
      MessageBox.Show("Operation failed,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
   }
}
```

The **val** variable is actually a base64 string that I am trying to pass. The reason I tried the above, is for this link - [Assign Image or Set face](https://desarrollo.zktecolatinoamerica.com/sdk/set_user_face_str). Though I failed, it throws error code 2. Is there anyone who faced the same situation or came up with a solution? This is one of my R & D project, so expecting some suggestions if this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The SFace900 model is designed to capture and store encrypted face templates rather than the actual face images for matching purposes. As a result, it does not support adding face images for attendance or punch recording.

If you require a solution that allows face recording for attendance purposes, I recommend considering the SpeedFace(AI) series models. These models are capable of capturing and processing face images for accurate matching and attendance tracking.

Alternatively, if you prefer a cloud-based API solution, you can explore the cams utron multiface model. It provides a comprehensive API that supports face recording and offers advanced features for efficient attendance management.

Feel free to choose the model that best suits your needs and requirements.